# Encrypt Windows partition with TrueCrypt, decrypt under Linux?

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt

Is there any way I can fully encrypt a windows partition so that encryption is in real time and transparent, and when I boot into my Linux partition be able to decrypt it and access the file son there?

I know that I could use an encrypted file container instead, but that is not ideal for me.

I also understand it may be possible to encrypt the entire drive, without regard to specific partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My situation:

- Installed win7 64-bit
- Installed TrueCrypt 7.0
- In preferences activated hardware accelerated AES (it makes the use of TrueCrypt use neglible CPU cycles)
- Instructed TrueCrypt to encrypt my entire system drive
- On boot you now get a bootloader asking for the password and initially a background scan that encrypts everything.  Thereafter it's just transparent doing it in the background

Now, a few months after running this config your question made me curious, as I might like to do it as well, I did the following:

- Booted Ubunto 64-bit from a live cd
- Installed TrueCrypt
- Mounted my HD, but choosing sda2 from the device dialog, and checking the checkbox for "Mount partition using system encryption (pre-boot authentication)"
- Browsed it from the Ubuntu explorer

So I can confirm you can do what you want to do by following the steps above.  Also, as an FYI, I'm very happy with the above config

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about TrueCrypt, the answer is no. You would have to use a file container.